# Outlook - Flagged items appear in unflagged group

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

In my Outlook I created a rule that flags all incoming emails. In my inbox I have grouped my emails by flag status. If I complete an email, I flag it as complete. Following this regime, there should be two folders in my inbox: flagged and complete. Still, items end up in a unflagged folder. This happens to Outlook invites. I can't figure out why this is, can somebody help me with this?

[image: I added a screenshot to show the problem.]

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 fields you can group, both are related to flags. One is called Flagged, while the other is called Flag status. You need to group on the Flag status for it to work, the other one doesn't work at all.

Given that I actually not use an english version, the names may differ slightly.

Comment: I actually do this, I think. See image: https://imgur.com/a/xLUR5

Comment: Hmm, indeed. That should work then.